# Obtaining max and min values in Clojure

Tags: clojure, max, min

I am trying to pull the maximum and minimum results from an SQL query into Clojure so that I can perform a mathematical analysis on them but I am unsure as to why I am getting an error.

I have used the max and min functions in the code to try and determine these results although I keep getting two errors back that seem to relate to the way I am using the **:counter** keyword.

The data returned in a map from the SQL query looks like this:

```
    {:date1 "20131007", :data "object1", :counter 1000}
    {:date1 "20131007", :data "object2", :counter 50}
    {:date1 "20131007", :data "object3", :counter 230}
```

When I use this code:

```
    minvalue(min(map(keyword :counter)data2))
    maxvalue(max(map(keyword :counter)data2))
    valrange(- maxvalue minvalue)
    valpc(* (/ valrange 100) 10)
    x(- maxvalue valpc)
```

I would obviously want **minvalue** to be set as 50 and **maxvalue** to be set to 1000 although I am getting this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

If I remove the map function from the code and run it again, I get this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

Any help is appreciated on this as I'm completely stuck (and its probably pretty ovbious that I'm a novice at Clojure)! Thanks

Comment: A note about performance: if you have larger numbers of maps to process, using reduce (something like `(reduce min (:counter (first maps)) (map :counter (rest maps)))`) will be more efficient than apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few changes from your code:

- min and max take a variable number of parameters, rather than a collection. Use apply to, well apply the contents of a collection as parameters instead.
- Clojure naming conventions use - between words
- Valid calls have to be in a form (basically a list where the first item is callable)
- No need to use "keyword", keyword is for when you have a string and need an associated keyword. For dragging data out of maps keywords act as functions themselves e.g (:a {:a 1 :b 2}) returns 1.
- Factored out the commonality in your first two lines

  ```
  (def data [{:date1 "20131007", :data "object1", :counter 1000}
             {:date1 "20131007", :data "object2", :counter 50}
             {:date1 "20131007", :data "object3", :counter 230}])

  (def counters (map :counter data))      ; => (100 50 230)
  (def min-value (apply min counters))    ; => 50
  (def max-value (apply max counters))    ; => 1000
  (def val-range (- max-value min-value)) ; => 950
  (def val-pc (* (/ val-range 100) 10))   ; => 95
  (def x (- max-value val-pc))            ; => 905
  ```

Answer (score 6):

```
user=> data
[{:data "object1", :date1 "20131007", :counter 1000} {:data "object2", :date1 "20131007", :counter 50} {:data "object3", :date1 "20131007", :counter 230}]

user=> (apply max-key :counter data)
{:data "object1", :date1 "20131007", :counter 1000}

user=> (apply min-key :counter data)
{:data "object2", :date1 "20131007", :counter 50}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried the code above and I am still getting the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number. I am only looking for the actual integer value from the :counter key to be returned so that I can work with the actual value. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you want just the value use `(apply min (map :counter data))` or `(reduce min (map :counter data))`. The code above and this code works. `data` should be a vector of maps.